# web based booking systems

Tags: web-services

I am an IB(International Baccalaureate) student, and for preparing for my ITGS(Information Technologies in Global Societies) exam, and I would like to ask few questions to people who has worked with web-based booking systems.

Here are the questions;

*Could you please describe the booking system you are using ?

*If so, how did you build your interactive booking system ?(Java, Flash, Javascript)

*If you are using Flash for your interactive booking system, how did you manage the problem with smart phones and tablet devices that doesn’t support flash?

*What can you say when you compare the cost of building your booking system and the other alternatives ?

*What difficulties you went through when you made your system ?

*What are the advantages of using such a system ? Why did you prefer to do so ?

*ls your system multilingual ? If not, why ?

*If so, what are the difficulties of having a multi-lingual web-site? How did you solve these problems ?

These are the questions I sent to some companies, who never replied back, so you may find them a little bit weird

Any help will do

Thanks